# How to set AlertDialog left and right margin?

Tags: android

I want to set left and right margins to 40dp

```
AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_dialog, null);
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);

AppCompatTextView title = new AppCompatTextView(this);
int innerPadding_px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 24, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
int outerPaddingLeftRight_px = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, 40, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

title.setPadding(innerPadding_px, innerPadding_px, innerPadding_px, innerPadding_px);
AlertDialog alertDialog = dialogBuilder.create();


WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParams = alertDialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
```

I try like this, but it isn't working

```
layoutParams.horizontalMargin = outerPaddingLeftRight_px;
alertDialog.getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParams);
alertDialog.setTitle("Выбрать автомобиль");
alertDialog.show();
```

Comment: What root layout are you using for the R.layout.content_dialog? RelativeLayout, LinearLayout?

Comment: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="24dp"
    android:layout_margin="60dp">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@android:drawable/arrow_down_float"/>
</LinearLayout>`

Answer (score 0):

When you inflate your view you can add custom layout parameters to the view to allow for dynamic margins.

Inflate dialog view.

```
View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.content_dialog, null);
```

Get layout parameters for the linear layout view. We assume you are using LinearLayout from the xml code you pasted in the comments section.

```
LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = dialogView.getLayoutParams();
```

Set the margins you wish to set.

```
layoutParams.horizontalMargin = outerPaddingLeftRight_px;
```

Ask the layout to please relayout your views since you have updated the layout params.

```
dialogView.requestLayout();
```

Finally set the new shiny view to your Alert Dialog builder.

```
dialogBuilder.setView(dialogView);
```

Comment: on `dialogView.getLayoutParams()` it says `Required: android.widget.LinearLayout.LayoutParams` `Found: android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams` and the `LinearLayout.LayoutParams` haven't **`.horizontalMargin`**

Comment: You can statically cast it LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams =  (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) dialogView.getLayoutParams();

Comment: I think it's impossible... :) i have to try everything .......... on api 19 there is no any margins :)